# What are these? Received from children's centre in free pack

Tags: infant, newborn

A friend received this baby pack from our local [Sure Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sure_Start) center (they're a UK children's initiative for those who don't know).  It contained various, obviously useful items for people with a baby and these (pictured). We don't know what they are but we're assuming they're some kind of baby proofing device? Does anyone recognize what they are? There's no information or instructions in the pack.

[image: Odd Items]

Comment: This question is as puzzling as [the one about the dinosaur](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/574/does-anyone-recognize-where-the-phrase-dinosaur-on-the-button-comes-from)!

Comment: What else is in the pack?  Maybe the context will help.

Comment: Mainly books and leaflets..  and these..

Comment: Corner/Edge guards?  Or maybe something to do with cords?

Comment: I am not finding a photo to verify, but I think it might be for tidying up blind cords to baby doesn't hang himself.

Comment: Could you provide more pictures, including some from the leaflets ?

Comment: IQ test for parents?

Comment: Do you know what type of pack it was, Sure Start do several `Maternity Pack, Safety Pack, Baby Book Start, Book Start Plus, Breast Feeding, Dental Pack Baby, Dental Pack Toddler`. Also are they solid/rigid, or are they flexible/rubbery?

Comment: Google image search says that they are shoes. I'm with the others though, is there any additional information?

Comment: Call 02890 860 938 and they will tell you about this stuff. You can also try to send them an e-mail, see more at their [web site](http://www.abbeysurestart.co.uk/Contactus.html).

Comment: Be sure to also let them know how confusing these are without instructions.

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: I also believe they are blind cord cleats. You can find out more about the dangers of blind cords here:
https://www.rospa.com/campaigns-fundraising/current/blind-cord/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like something for wrapping up and securing draw cords on blinds.  You would wrap the cord between the diamond shaped piece and the long piece.  You can then insert the cord into the holes in the diamond piece to keep it from coming unraveled.  This way you can shorten the strings so kids can't choke themselves on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.  they would be great for installing at the back of a drawer to prevent it from being pulled all the way out and onto a little toddler.  the two "holes" at the corner of the diamond section are the mounting points.  Position it so that the forward-curving section is above the level of the drawer, so that it will catch the upper drawer frame when the drawer gets pulled out far enough that it might fall out.